# find euclidean distance between values in c

Tags: c, cmusphinx

i need your help. I want to find euclidean distance between each value of the two mfc files generated in sphinx3. My problem is that i have to pass two wav files such as a.wav and b.wav in which b.wav is a subpart of a.wav. I have generated .mfc in text format and it is like this

```
11.143 1.3739 -0.18189 -0.46588 0.081962 -0.053194 -0.039629 -0.19989 -0.28369 -0.41381 -0.38511 -0.25862 -0.017158
11.013 1.2289 -0.28845 -0.51773 -0.049813 -0.0025347 -0.10207 -0.23056 -0.33524 -0.27521 -0.37585 -0.36463 -0.06067
10.999 1.2356 -0.1489 -0.39382 -0.029506 0.054779 0.12997 -0.11465 -0.27684 -0.40508 -0.4854 -0.31248 -0.19142
10.977 1.235 -0.18344 -0.61799 -0.12633 -0.049641 0.039414 -0.16939 -0.1884 -0.34448 -0.27235 -0.20559 -0.23409
10.987 1.2966 -0.12835 -0.4269 -0.14144 -0.14519 -0.06445 -0.19406 -0.19799 -0.29742 -0.41959 -0.17827 -0.029767
11.035 1.4875 -0.23199 -0.51662 -0.045337 -0.024595 -0.079227 -0.20181 -0.25853 -0.43788 -0.47611 -0.33845 -0.082532
```

Now i want to compute euclidean distance between each value of a.mfc and b.mfc. This is possible in Matlab but it is taking too much time. I want this to be done in C language. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you read the .mfc file in C? Are the a.mfc and b.mfc have same number of values? If so you could read the two files into two seperate arrays and do the Eculidean distance calculation.

Comment: mfc's are generated in sphinx3 in text format using sphinx3_decode, and it contains some values as mentioned above. No number of values in these text files are different. Now i want to compute euclidean distance between each element of these two text files and store them into an array.

Comment: please tell if there is any way of computing euclidean distance between frames of mfcc in sphinx3....Is there any kind of executable file like sphinx3_decode, sphinx3_astar that can do this job???? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not particularly well formulated. AFAIK mfc files contain vectors with 13 elements. Some untested code would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define VECSIZE 13

void readvec(char* s, float* v) {
  // read one vector from s into v
  char* h;
  h = strtok(s, " ");
  int i = 0;
  while (h != NULL && i < VECSIZE) {
    v[i++] = atof(h);
    h = strtok(NULL, " ");
  }
  while (i < VECSIZE)
    v[i++] = .0;
}

bool compareFiles() {
  FILE* a = fopen("a.wav", "r");
  FILE* b = fopen("b.wav", "r");
  FILE* res = fopen("res.wav", "w");  // results file

  if (a == NULL || b == NULL || res == NULL)
    return false;

  char* sa[1024];
  char* sb[1024];
  float va[VECSIZE];
  float vb[VECSIZE];
  while (!feof(a) && !feof(b)) {
    fgets(sa, 1024, a);
    readvec(sa, va);
    fgets(sb, 1024, b);
    readvec(sb, vb);
    float diff =.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < VECSIZE; i++)
      diff += pow(va[i] - vb[i], 2);
    diff = sqrt(diff);
    fprintf(res, "%f\n", diff);
  }
  fclose(a);
  fclose(b);
  fclose(res);
  return true;
}
```

Comment: mfc's are generated in sphinx3 in text format using sphinx3_decode, and it contains some values as mentioned above. No number of values in these text files are different. Now i want to compute euclidean distance between each element of these two text files and store them into an array.

Comment: please tell if there is any way of computing euclidean distance between frames of mfcc in sphinx3....Is there any kind of executable file like sphinx3_decode, sphinx3_astar that can do this job???? Thank you

Comment: Well, I don't know anything about sphinx3. The above code write the euclidean distances into a file (res.wav), you can easily change it to store them in an array. Unfortunately I can't give you a C course here... :)

Comment: There are potential resource leaks (File* a, b, res should be closed before any function return). Suggested changes:    
  FILE* a = fopen("a.wav", "r");
  if (a == NULL) return false;
  FILE* b = fopen("b.wav", "r");
  if (b == NULL) {
    fclose(a);
    return false;
  }
  FILE* res = fopen("res.wav", "w");  // results file
  if (res == NULL) {
    fclose(a);
    fclose(b);
    return false;
  }